# Closed bounded subsets of X are compact. X complete?

Tags: real-analysis

If X is a metric space with the property that every closed, bounded subset of X is compact, is X complete?  If so, can you provide a proof? Thank you.

Comment: Consider the closure of the underlying set of a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Can you be more detailed?

Comment: Think of $X=(0,1)$. Is $X$ complete?

Comment: No, since 1/n converges to 0 (and hence is Cauchy) but 0 does not lie in the interval.  Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: In $(0,1)$, is the closure of $\{ 1/n : n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geqslant 2\}$ compact?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $\langle X,d\rangle$ be a metric space. Suppose that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$ that has no limit. Let $A=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$.

- Show that $A$ is bounded.
- Show that $A$ is closed.
- Show that $A$ is not compact.

Conclude that if every closed, bounded set in $X$ is compact, then $\langle X,d\rangle$ is complete.